# Nginx proxy_pass without path

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm configuring an Nginx reverse proxy that should do the following:

- `/` => proxied to `http://server:8080/api/resolver`
- `/somepath1` => proxied to `http://server:8080/api/resolver` (should drop the path `somepath1`)
- `/someotherpath2` => proxied to `http://server:8080/api/resolver` (should drop the path `someotherpath2`)
- `/app1` => served from `/var/www/app1`
- `/someimage.jpg` => served from `/var/www/app1/someimage.jpg`
- `/someimage.jpg?1234` => served from `/var/www/app1/someimage.jpg`
- `/assets/someimage.jpg` => served from `/var/www/app1/assets/someimage.jpg`

This is a simplified version of my existing configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass              http://server:8080/api/resolver;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Connection "";

        location ~ ^/(.+\.(?:js|css|png|jpe?g|svg|ttf|woff|json))(?:\?.*)*$ {
            alias /var/www/app1/$1;
        }
    }

    location /app1 {
        absolute_redirect off;
        root              /var/www;
        try_files         $uri $uri/ /app1/index.html =404;
    }

    location /assets/ {
        root              /var/www/app1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that paths like `/somepath1` and `/someotherpath2` are being proxied to `http://server:8080/api/resolversomepath1` and `http://server:8080/api/resolversomeotherpath2`, which is not what I'm looking for. Instead, the path in those cases should be dropped and proxied to `http://server:8080/api/resolver`.

The complication is that these paths are not known in advanced (so can't add specific locations for it), since `/` serves a SPA (Single Page Application), these routes can be anything that is defined in the webapp code.

I've tried a few different approaches, including using the `redirect` directive in the `location /` block without luck.

Any ideas?